# How to handle Spinner position in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-recyclerview

**i have 2 Views in listView and`if (position == 0)` repidly called again and again how to prevent it?**

**1:- i want when spinner change the value then  `notifyDataSetChanged();` for update the list**

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch (viewType) {
        case LAYOUT_ZERO_INDEX:
                holder.materialDesignSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if (position == 0) {
                             dataarry.clear();
                            dataarry.add(0, 1000);
                            dataarry.add(1, 5000);
                            dataarry.add(2, 6000);
                            dataarry.add(3, 8000);
                            dataarry.add(4, 3500);
                            dataarry.add(5, 4000);
                            dataarry.add(6, 5500);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            setData(6, 8000, holder);
                            holder.mChart.invalidate();
                        }
                     if (position == 1) {
                            dataarry.clear();
                            dataarry.add(0, 5500);
                            dataarry.add(1, 4500);
                            dataarry.add(2, 5200);
                            dataarry.add(3, 7000);
                            dataarry.add(4, 7000);
                            dataarry.add(5, 6000);
                            dataarry.add(6, 7800);
        //                        mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
    //                        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
          //                        mChart.clear();
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            setData(6, 8000, holder);
                            holder.mChart.invalidate();
                            // setData(6, 8000);
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
       (context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, weeklist);
                holder.materialDesignSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                holder.mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
                setData(6, 8000, holder);


            if (position == 1) {
                holder.year.setText("ahmad");
                holder.year.setText("Mon,Oct 2");
                holder.earning.setText("Rs 1200");
                holder.trips.setText("10 سفر");
            }
            break;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
int positonOld=0;
int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
switch (viewType) {
    case LAYOUT_ZERO_INDEX:
            holder.materialDesignSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    if(position==positonOld){
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    positonOld=positon;

                    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if (position == 0) {
                        dataarry.clear();
                        dataarry.add(0, 1000);
                        dataarry.add(1, 5000);
                        dataarry.add(2, 6000);
                        dataarry.add(3, 8000);
                        dataarry.add(4, 3500);
                        dataarry.add(5, 4000);
                        dataarry.add(6, 5500);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        setData(6, 8000, holder);
                        holder.mChart.invalidate();
                    }
                    if (positionn == 1) {
                        dataarry.clear();
                        dataarry.add(0, 5500);
                        dataarry.add(1, 4500);
                        dataarry.add(2, 5200);
                        dataarry.add(3, 7000);
                        dataarry.add(4, 7000);
                        dataarry.add(5, 6000);
                        dataarry.add(6, 7800);
    //                        mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
//                        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
      //                        mChart.clear();
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        setData(6, 8000, holder);
                        holder.mChart.invalidate();
                        // setData(6, 8000);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
   (context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, weeklist);
            holder.materialDesignSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            holder.mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
            setData(6, 8000, holder);


        if (position == 1) {
            holder.year.setText("ahmad");
            holder.year.setText("Mon,Oct 2");
            holder.earning.setText("Rs 1200");
            holder.trips.setText("10 سفر");
        }
        break;
}
```

}